# Working with AIG Raster format in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, format

I downloaded a specific layer which has the format "AIG" as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Properties of Raster Layer]
[image]

It has no projection so I applied "Define Projection" on it. I searched for the projection and found the following:

> 4.1 - INDIRECT SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM:
>
> Type of indirect spatial reference system:
>
> By country.
>
> Reference date:
>    2001.
>
> 4.2 - DIRECT SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM:
>
> Datum:  Lambert Azimuthal.
>
> Ellipsoid: Sphere.
>
> Map projection: Projection    LAMBERT_AZIMUTHAL
>
> Units                    METERS
>              Spheroid         SPHERE
>
> Major Axis        6378388.00000
>               Minor Axis       0.00000
>
> Parameters:
>
> radius of the sphere of reference                      6378388.00000
>
> longitude of centre of projection                        9  0  0.000
>
> latitude of centre of projection                        48  0  0.000
>
> false easting (meters)                                       0.00000
>
> false northing (meters)                                      0.00000

The problem I have is that if search for this projection I get these two

[image]

After applying the first one using "Define Projection", nothing changes in the file. By this I mean the spatial reference is still "undefined" and the coordinate system is unknown. I also tried other projections but nothing works. If I convert it to a polygon first, define projection works but the reference on the map is still completely wrong. I think these problems occur because of the "uncommon" raster format?

I also think that the projection from the screenshot is not equal to the one I posted up here?

My goal is to project it in the end to "British National Grid" as all my layers I work with have this projection.

I also tried it on another computer with ArcGIs 10.2 and the same problem occured.

See these FME links for further reference to the AIG format:

- [Esri ArcGIS Binary Grid (AIG) Reader](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2014beta/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#arcviewgrid/arcviewgrid.htm)
- [Esri ArcGIS Binary Grid Quick Facts](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2014beta/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#arcviewgrid/ArcGIS_Binary_Grid_Quick.htm)

[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Hey Brad, I applied the Projection of the UK Layer, the "British National Grid"- Projection. I also tried others, like WGS 84 just to see if it works but nothing changed.

Comment: applying a random projection to a dataset does not change the values in the dataset.

Comment: Please search some of the projection finding questions. Also edit your original question with more info. don't continue leaving comments. I imagine the mxd you are working in is set to undefined projection. that is why nothing changes when you apply different projections.

Comment: Note the Define Projection tool will not change the projection of the coordinates, it just updates the projection definition, i.e. the metadata. Can you edit your question to include the extent coordinates of the raster.

Comment: Rewrote the question!